# Synchronously populate/modify an array and return the modified array inside a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, synchronous

I'm pretty new to ReactJS and redux, so I've never really had to work with this before. I'm retrieving data from an API call in my project. I want to modify the data by adding a new property to the object. However, because the code is not ran synchronously, the unmodified array is being returned (I assume) instead of the modified array.

```js
export function loadThings() {
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
     type: 'LOAD_THINGS',
     payload: {
       request: {
         url: API_GET_THINGS_ENDPOINT,
         method: 'GET'
       }
     }
    }).then(response => {
      let things = response.payload.data;
      // Retrieve all items for the loaded "things"
      if(things) {
        things.forEach((thing, thingIndex) => {
            things[thingIndex].items = []
            if (thing.hasOwnProperty('channels') && thing.channels) {
              thing.channels.forEach(channel => {
                if (channel.hasOwnProperty('linkedItems') && channel.linkedItems) {
                  channel.linkedItems.forEach(itemName => {
                    dispatch(loadItems(itemName)).then(
                      item => things[thingIndex].items.push(item) // push the items inside the "things"
                    )
                  })
                }
              })
            }
        })
      }
      things.forEach(data => console.log(data.items.length, data.items)) // data.items.length returns 0, data.items returns a populated array
      return things // return the modified array
    }).catch(error => {
      //todo: handle error
      return false
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see, I perform an API call which returns data named `response`. The array is populated with all "things". If `things` exists, I want to load extra information named "items". Based on the information in the things array, I will perform another API call (which is done by dispatching the `loadItems` function) which returns another `promise`. Based on the data in the results of that API call, I will push into the `items` property (which is an array) of the `things` object.

As you can see in the comments, if I loop through the `things` array and log the `items` property which I just created, it's basically returning 0 as length, which means the `things` array is being returned before the `things` array is being modified.

I would like to know two things:

- What is causing my code to run async. Is it the
  `dispatch(loadItems(itemName))` function since it returns a promise?
- How am I able to synchronously execute my code?

Please note: this function `loadThings()` also returns a promise (if you're not familair with redux).

**You might be interested in knowing what I tried myself to fix the code**

Since I fail to understand the logic why the code is ran async, I've been trying hopeless stuff. Such as wrapping the code in another `Promise.all` and return the modified array in that promise. I used the `then` method of that promise to modify the `things` array, which had the exact same result. Probably because `return things` is being executed outside of that `promise`.

I'd really love to know what is going on

**Edit**
I have added the `loadItems()` code to the question, as requested:

```js
export function loadItems(itemName) {
  return dispatch => {
    const url = itemName ? API_GET_ITEMS_ENDPOINT + `/${itemName}` : API_GET_ITEMS_ENDPOINT;
    return dispatch({
      type: 'LOAD_ITEMS',
      payload: {
        request: {
          url: url,
          method: 'GET'
        }
      }
    }).then(response => {
      return response.payload.data
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `dispatch(loadItems(itemName))` starts an async call whose result you eventually handle in the `item => things[thingIndex].items.push(item)` but that will typically happen long after `return things` has already happened.

Comment: You will need to return a promise instead of `return things` that will resolve later when all the `dispatch(loadItems(itemName))` have finished. You should use `Promise.all()` to wait for multiple promises to finish.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `loadItems()` function?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @JonasBerlin. I'm going to try to implement what you said. I have also added the `loadItems()` code

Comment: @JonasBerlin I unfortunately wasn't able to do it. I fail to seem to understand how I would wrap the code in a Promise.all() inside of two foreach loops. It can't be that hard, but I just can't see it at this moment.

Comment: if something in the then/catch chains returns a promise, the promise will only continue with the next item of the chain when those promises are also resolved, so if you would do a `return Promise.all( someArray.map( FromItemToPromiseRequest ) )` it would wait until all those items have completed and then return an array of the results from those calls back to you (that might be oversimplifying the code you need, but it gives a hint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach would be to map over `things`, creating arrays of promises for all of their items wrapped in a `Promise.all`, which gives you an array of `Promise.all`'s.

Then you return `things` and this array of promises in another `Promise.all` and in the next then block, you can just assign the arrays to each `thing` with a simple for loop:

```js
export function loadThings() {
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
      type: 'LOAD_THINGS',
      payload: {
        request: {
          url: API_GET_THINGS_ENDPOINT,
          method: 'GET'
        }
      }
    }).then(response => {
      let things = response.payload.data;
      // Retrieve all items for the loaded "things"
      const items = things.map((thing) => {
        const thingItems = []
        if (thing.hasOwnProperty('channels') && thing.channels) {
          thing.channels.forEach(channel => {
            if (channel.hasOwnProperty('linkedItems') && channel.linkedItems) {
              channel.linkedItems.forEach(itemName => {
                thingItems.push(dispatch(loadItems(itemName)));
              });
            }
          });
        }

        return Promise.all(thingItems);
      });

      return Promise.all([things, Promise.all(items)])
    })
    .then(([things, thingItems]) => {
      things.forEach((thing, index) => {
        thing.items = thingItems[index];
      })

      return things;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //todo: handle error
      return false
    })
  }
}
```

Edit:
You need to push the `dispatch(loadItmes(itemName))` calls directly into `thingItems`.

Comment: I understand the code, it's simple, it's clear and I could combine this with the answer of Icepickle, I believe. I did replace `return Promise.all(thingItems)` with `return thingItems` because I believe the data should be returned or a resolved promise (please, correct me if I'm wrong. Still new to Promises). Returning `return Promise.all(thingItems)` resulted in returning empty arrays. Returning `thingItems` resulted in a populated array with the correct data.

However, the code is still continuing even when `dispatch(loadItems(itemName))` has not completed. Is that because of my "fix"?

Comment: Oh my bad, there is a bug, let me fix that for you. You don't want `.then()` inside of the `forEach` instead, just push the promises directly into `thingItems`. I've reflected this change in my answer above.

Comment: That makes sense! Now I understand why you wanted to return promises. Wish I thought of that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could refactor it like the following:

```
export function loadThings() {
  return dispatch => {
    return dispatch({
     type: 'LOAD_THINGS',
     payload: {
       request: {
         url: API_GET_THINGS_ENDPOINT,
         method: 'GET'
       }
     }
    }).then(response => {
      let things = response.payload.data;
      // Retrieve all items for the loaded "things"
      if( things ) {
        return Promise.all( things.reduce( (promises, thing) => {
          if (thing.channels) {
            thing.items = [];
            promises.push( ...thing.channels.map( channel => 
              channel.linkedItems && 
              channel.linkedItems.map( item => 
                loadItems(item).then( result => thing.items.push( result ) ) 
              ) ).flat().filter( i => !!i ) );
          }
          return promises;
        }, []) );
      }
      return things;
    }).catch(error => {
      //todo: handle error
      return false
    })
  }
}
```

In case you would have `things`, it would check for the channels and the `linkedItems` for that channel, and create a promise that will push the result back to the `thing.items` array.

By returning the `Promise.all`, the continuation of the `loadThings` would only complete when the `Promise.all` was resolved. In case there are no things, just things gets returned (which would be a falsy value, so I am wondering how valid that statement could be)

I haven't actually tested the refactoring so there might be some brackets in need of adjusting to your situation, but I guess it gives you an idea?

Comment: I do get the idea and I think this piece of code is pure art. I'm going to try to figure out why the data inside `return promises` is undefined. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanR thats because the inner promise only sets the items, it doesnt return anything, if you want that, you need to return result still